# Why Gnome Terminal doesn't display a specific font as available

Tags: 14.10, fonts, gnome-terminal

Commands I've tried:

- `sudo updatedb`
- `sudo fc-cache -fv`
- `sudo reboot`

Dispite this I was unable to make [Monofur](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/Monofur) font to display as available for the Gnome Terminal in a machine with Ubuntu 14.10 recently installed. It's available in all other apps.

I have other machine with 14.04 where this went fine.

I'm not sure whether this is related with a problem when I installed the font for the first time and the font manager got stuck when installing that I had to reboot. Afterwards I've removed the font from the system and reinstalled it without problems.

It's in `~/.local/share/fonts`.

`fc-list` lists this font. File permissions are OK.

## UPDATE

Upgraded to last Ubuntu, issue vanished.

Comment: Installing this font and selecting it as default in gnome-terminal worked for me straightaway, even without any of the commands you mention. It's in my `.local/share/fonts` folder as well.

Comment: @Jos Maybe something went wrong when I've installed it for the first time and had to force reboot. But I've tried to remove it from any possible place it could be before reinstalling, still nothing. I can't select it since it doesn't display as an option.

Comment: Can you use Monofur in other applications, e. g. LibreOffice or GEdit?

Comment: @DavidFoerster yes.

Comment: @pepper_chico so , how is it ? no solution yet ?

Comment: @Serg nope, I didn't try to uninstall the Terminal though, I thought it was too much for this.

Comment: The monofur font creator specifically says that the font has to be used in large enough sizes due to hinting problems.  What font size are you using and have you tried 11, 12, 13 or 14 point?

Comment: @Fabby yes, and I think it has no effect about it being at last displayed as an option. Gnome Terminal just don't list it for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 8):

First see if the font is available in system by using `fc-list | grep font-name`.

Now copy the font name correctly from the result of above command e.g.

`/usr/share/fonts/TTF/MonofurNerd/monofur Nerd Font Complete.ttf: Monofur Nerd Font:style=Book`.

For this font name is `Monofur Nerd Font` which comes after `.ttf:`.

Now open `dconf-editor` GUI version.
Now navigate to the font setting of gnome-terminal.
`/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:some-id/`

Here `:some-id` is a long set of characters which refer to your profiles in `gnome-terminal`.

Then find the font setting, and change the font name by the one you want.

Apply the settings and you are done.

Comment: This is the only one which reliably works for me

Answer (score 6):

Whatever I did I couldn't get my fonts to show up. I got at a point where I tried switching random options, and when I switched "Allow bold text" off and back on all the fonts showed up. Don't ask me why but it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! This was what worked for me finally. Weird, though!

Comment: Sadly, this option is missing in Ubuntu 18.04.  I toggled it using `dconf-editor` per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046802/how-to-re-enable-bold-texts-in-terminal), but it didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Having installed the font, it didn't show right away for me either. Here's the steps I took to make it show up:

**1) Move the font to /usr/share/fonts/truetype` directory**:

Create a directory `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Monofur/` and move the font files (in my case, I only moved `Monofur for Powerline.ttf`) either with file manager or with `mv` command. Note, you will need sudo priviliges for all that

**2) Delete everything in ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/**

The profile preferences are all stored in `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/` directory. I basically did `sudo rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/`

**3) Close and reopen gnome-terminal**

Self- explanatory.

**Suggestions**:

For good measure, try doing `updatedb` after deleting everything or after reopening gnome-terminal; try rebooting if it still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry but this didn't work, even after reboot.

Comment: What's the permissions on the files by the way?

Comment: All `-rw-r--r--` (same as for other fonts in other directories). I need all the 3 fonts by the way, so I've copied all of them.

Comment: Weird. I've no other ideas so far.

Comment: Had a thought : how about attempting a reinstall of gnome-terminal ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've upgraded Ubuntu in my job and this has been fixed at last \o/. No idea why it didn't worked on 14.10 but I don't care anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using https://superuser.com/questions/1335155/patched-fonts-not-showing-up-on-gnome-terminal link.

On Amazon Linux 2, I did the following,

1. Installed `gnome-tweaks`

   `sudo yum install gnome-tweaks`
2. Ran `gnome-tweaks`
3. Fonts (sidebar) -> Monospace (select whatever font is needed). This selects the default font.
4. Close `gnome-tweaks`
5. Open `gnome-terminal`
6. Edit -> preferences -> Profiles (sidebar) -> Text -> Custom font (**uncheck** it i.e. use the default system wide font)