# How to re-enable bold texts in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, text

In old versions of Ubuntu, there was "allow bold texts" option in preference settings of gnome-terminal. I used to turn it off.

But in recent versions, it seems the option is gone, and I'm stuck in only non-bold texts. How can I re-enable bold texts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME Terminal 3.28) this preference is still available as a hidden one, it's just no longer displayed on the UI.

You can change it with `dconf` (conveniently using `dconf-editor`), under `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:<profile-id>/allow-bold`.

Also, newly created (from scratch, that is, not cloned) profiles set it to the default value, i.e. enabled.

Comment: And if one is without dconf-editor, `dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:<profile-id>/allow-bold true` (optionally substituting `true` for `false`) works as well.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! +1